# Propagating a custom block to child pages

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

So I have a custom block that displays a banner image on top of a parent page. I want the custom block to be automatically copied to all the child pages. Which means the child pages will also have the same banner image as the parent.

I have searched around the internet on how to do this but I have not found any solution. I only found [plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/get-subpages-list/) that allows me to display the child pages but that is not what I need.

Does anyone have experience in doing this? Or can anybody point me to the right direction to start with. I'm really feeling hopeless at the moment. Is this possible with gutenberg?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there's no native way to accomplish this.
I normally create a template page with all of the blocks I expect to use and duplicate that as needed.
Depending on your implementation, I'd recommend [looking at this page for block templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-templates/) and see what applies. [This article](https://richtabor.com/gutenberg-block-templates/) has more details on how to use block templates.

Comment: Hi @juan

I have another approach to this but I’m not sure if it is also doable.

Suppose, I have a parent page, with a custom banner block — where the block displays a banner image.

On the child page, I would use the same custom banner block but there would be the option to input a url. The url provided would be where I want to copy the banner it has. So in the child page, I would input the url of the parent page and I want it to pull the banner image and display it also in there. Is this doable?

Cheers

Comment: Hmmm I don't think I've done this myself for custom blocks but it sounds like it should be possible. If you're using ACF for custom fields, in the block template, get that page's ID from the URL (or use a Link field that returns an array and get the ID from that) and pass in the parent page ID for the second argument to get that content, `the_field('customField', PageID);`